# How do I make a text box accept only int between 1 to 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for hours. How do I make the program takes only values from 1 to 6 or else it crashes?

> "user only enters acceptable credit hours-- every credit hours entered is an integer between 0 and 6 and nothing else. In this case, any invalid or bad or empty input data will cause a run-time error, which is expected and is fine."

this is one of the methods i tried that did not work. I need to find out how to make the program just give a runtime error. I dont need to keep asking for input or display a message saying "error"

```
creditHours = double.Parse(tb_credit.Text);

if (creditHours != 1 || creditHours != 2 || creditHours != 3 || 
    creditHours != 4 || creditHours != 5 || creditHours != 6)
{ 
    creditHours = double.Parse(tb_credit.Text); 
}
```

Comment: This is asp.net. Use a RangeValidator.

Answer (score 1):

Mehdi is correct, however here's why your code doesn't work.

Let's say the user entered "2", then

```
if(creditHours != 1 || ...)
{

}
```

would be true because creditHours is not equal to 1, it is 2.  But then let's say that the user enters "9", `if(creditHours != 1 || ...)` would still be true again because creditHours is not equal to 1 and is instead 9.  Hence both valid and invalid values yield the same result.  To correct your code you would need `if(creditHours == 1 || ...)`.

Mehdi's code is much simpler, however I like to write;

```
if(0 <= creditHours && creditHours <= 6)
{

}
```

think it just reads better.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (creditHours < 0 || creditHours > 6)
{ 
    throw new Exception("Credit hours can only be between 0 and 6."); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What does throw new Exception  do exactly ? I'm new to C#

Comment: It will raise a runtime error. Please google try catch and exception in c#.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your condition is not right, because if the input number is 7 then then the condition  **if(creditHours != 1 || ...)** will return **true**.
   => you should validate by this condition if **(creditHours > 0 && creditHours < 6)**
2. If user input an invalid number( ex: "abc123xyz" ) then this code will throw exception:  **creditHours = double.Parse(tb_credit.Text)**
   => you should use TryParse to handle invalid number also.

Please check my solution as bellow:

```
if(!double.TryParse(tb_credit.Text, out var creditHours))
{
    throw new Exception("Credit hours should be a numbers between 0 and 6.");
}

if (creditHours > 0 || creditHours < 6)
{
    creditHours = double.Parse(tb_credit.Text);
}

throw new Exception("Credit hours should be a numbers between 0 and 6.")
```

Comment: The point of using `TryParse` is to avoid exceptions in the first place. Why throw an exeption if a `TrtParse` fails?